# Grouping XML nodes by attribute value

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js, xslt

Im new to xslt transformation and i need to regroup all the nodes that contain the same user name, and regroup the skills corresponding to this user, here is a simple example.
Input:

```html
<Rowsets>
    <Rowset>
        <Columns>
            <Column Description="" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="login" SQLDataType="1" SourceColumn="User_login"/>
            <Column Description="" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="longName" SQLDataType="1" SourceColumn="User_longName"/>
            <Column Description="" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="Competency" SQLDataType="1" SourceColumn="Competency"/>
        </Columns>
        <Row>
            <login>NG5E054</login>
            <longName>---</longName>
            <Competency>SKILL1</Competency>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <login>NG5E059</login>
            <longName>---</longName>
            <Competency>SKILL1</Competency>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <login>NG5E059</login>
            <longName>---</longName>
            <Competency>SKILL2</Competency>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <login>NG5E059</login>
            <longName>---</longName>
            <Competency>SKILL3</Competency>
        </Row>

    </Rowset>
</Rowsets>
```

And my desired output is :

```html
<Rowsets>
    <Rowset>
        <Columns>
            <Column Description="" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="login" SQLDataType="1" SourceColumn="User_login"/>
            <Column Description="" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="longName" SQLDataType="1" SourceColumn="User_longName"/>
            <Column Description="" MaxRange="1" MinRange="0" Name="Competency" SQLDataType="1" SourceColumn="Competency"/>
        </Columns>
        <Row>
            <login>NG5E054</login>
            <longName>---</longName>
            <Competency>SKILL1</Competency>
        </Row>
        <Row>
            <login>NG5E059</login>
            <longName>---</longName>
            <Competency>SKILL1, SKILL2, SKILL3</Competency>
        </Row>
    </Rowset>
</Rowsets>
```

Thank you

Comment: Do a search for XSLT grouping - it's the most often asked XSLT question here. Note that the answers are different for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="//Row/login[not(.=preceding::*)]">
            <xsl:variable name="login" select="."/>
            <Row>
                <login><xsl:value-of select="$login"/></login>
                <Competency>
                    <xsl:for-each select="//Row[login=$login]/Competency">
                        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">, </xsl:if>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </Competency>
            </Row>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Basically it creates a row for each unique login. Inside each row it concatenates all related skills.

This works with both XSLT 1.0 and 2.0.

Comment: @MehdiMAHHOU, if answer suits u r requirement, then tick the right mark.

Comment: This is not a good answer. Use *Muenchian grouping* in XSLT 1.0, and `xsl:for-each-group` in XSLT 2.0.